# AWS S3 Static Website Accessible at /page.html and not /page

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am new to `AWS` and using `S3` to host my static website! I have an html file, `page.html` and it should be acessible at `mydomain.com/page`. However, it is only accessible at `mydomain.com/page.html` :(. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately if you want this to work there are a couple of solutions that you can try.

For the first by creating an [index document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/IndexDocumentSupport.html) in a subfolder i.e. `/page/index.html` you would be able to access your site on `/page/`. This would work well if you're using a hierarchy.

However, if you have many many pages then you will need to use another solution that can rewrite the client site URL to your `.html` file.

For this you can use CloudFront with a Lambda@Edge function to perform this in the `Origin Request` stage. This function might look similar to the below.

```
import json
import os
 
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    request = event['Records'][0]['cf']['request']
    
    filepath, extension = os.path.splitext(request['uri'])
    
    if not extension:
        new_uri = request['uri'] + '.html'
        request['uri'] = new_uri
    
    return request
```

By doing this your users will see a nice clean path but when it goes to your origin it will append the extension.

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding ".htaccess" file in root directory folder with the following code

```
#Make pages render without their extension in the URL
Options +MultiViews
```